# double data-binding in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding

Is it possible to make a "double data-binding" with angularJS ?

I want to get `mat.Discipline[0].nom_FR` in an array that have `nom_FR`, `nom_DE`, `nom_EN` and `nom_IT`.

`mat.Langue[0].langue` give me "FR", "DE", "EN" or "IT" depending what language the user choose.

So I would like to use `{{mat.Langue[0].langue}}` to determine if the discipline should be `nom_FR`, `nom_DE` or another...

I try to do something like that:
`{{mat.Discipline[0].nom_{{mat.Langue[0].langue}}}}` but of course, it doesn't work...

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets notation:

```
{{mat.Discipline[0]["nom_" + mat.Langue[0].langue]}};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Saddly, it doesn't work... I don't have an error, but nothing appears in the HTML, like if he found nothing...

Comment: @Nooka10 well it probably solved the original problem but there's another one :) If you want post a jsfiddle I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it finally work! ^^

I use your answer, but in javascript and it work!

Here is what I do in my Javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.allMateriel.length; i ++) {
  var langue = vm.allMateriel[i].Langue[0].langue;
  vm.allMateriel[i].Discipline[0].nom = vm.allMateriel[i].Discipline[0]['nom_' + langue];
}
```